# Crawler stucks at last page

Tags: python

I have some crawler code with chromedriver and selenium in python which goes through different pages.
However it does not reach the last page.
For example the maximum number of pages = 9, number of rows in table = 10. It then will continue scraping page 8 and start over again with page 8 again infinite.

My looping code is looking like this:

```
def extract(page):
    while 1:
        pc = 1
        print ("Extracting Page: " + str(page))
        while pc <= 10:
            colpageprod(pc)
            browser.back()
            waitSmall()
            pc+=1
        try:
            np = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//li[@class="next"]/a').click()
            waitSmall()
        except:
            pass
        page +=1
        if page < 1:
            break
try:            
    extract(1)
```

Problem is that on the website the second last page has no "next" button.
How could we work with this in the code?

Comment: If the problem is the "next" button, you might need to change you `try: except:` block to get it to work. Then infinitive loop might be because of `page +=1` and `if page < 1:`. Looks like the break will never happen.

Comment: `except: return` might do the trick. But you have so many places in your code where you start over, that it's hard to be sure just by eyeballing it.